# Objective C Callbacks and Notifications

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm new to Objective-C and not a full time programmer. I'm beginning to understand the Model-View-Controller design pattern for differentiating the UI from the model. So the user takes an action and the view controller sends a message to the delegate (model). But I'm not sure what the best way to send actions from the delegate back to the view controller.

For example, the user pushes a button, the VC messages the Delegate. That part I understand. Then the delegate takes action, and following that the delegate wants to update the VC (e.g., update a label).

So what I missed (or have forgotten) is how this gets done, while maintaining separation between the UI and the model. I suppose I can use the notification center. Or I think I can just have the view controller pass a callback to the delegate. Or maybe there's another choice I don't know of.  Can someone give me a recommendation, please?

Comment: "The user pushes a button, the VC messages the Delegate. That part I understand." Consider that maybe you don't. Or at least that you've got the terminology mixed up.

Answer (score 4):

I think you're slightly misunderstanding the MVC paradigm.  Models should never be delegates of views, since models should have no dependencies or knowledge of any view classes.  Typically, a view sends a message to its delegate or target (if you're using target/action), which is usually a controller (often a subclass of `UIViewController` on iOS).  The controller then accesses data from the model and can update any views that need updating.  I'd recommend reading the [MVC fundamentals guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaDesignPatterns/CocoaDesignPatterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH6-SW1) for a more complete explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you're right, you could do all the notification-related things yourself (i.e. with NotificationCenter) but since we're talking about UI-Stuff here I would greatly recommend you to use `IBAction`-Methods and `IBOutlet`-Properties  in your code which you can easily connect to UI-Elements respectively their Callbacks in Interface Builder.

A very basic introduction to this topic can be found here:
[iPhone SDK Interface Builder basic training](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/iphone-sdk-interface-builder-basic-training/)
i hope that it is not too basic tough, and that I could lead you on the right track.

Answer (score -1):

First of all delegate is NOT a Model.

Model is something passive that only holds the data (DB, plist, array, dictionary etc.).
While delegate is some set of functions that exist in order to react to some events.
Delegate is more likely to be a view controller in your case.

The view controller should react to user's action.
If the button tap should display some data from your model in some label then view controller should do all the work (receive user's action, take the necessary data from the model and display it on the view...).

Comment: The model does not have to be passive.  It holds the business data and rules and methods associated with the business data.

Comment: Model shouldn't know the view or the controller. It can't perform actions on none of them. Only if you start messing all together. The methods that it may hold may have influence on the data itself ONLY. If you say that you use to perform actions in view controller or view layers from your model then I wouldn't hire you...